# QSettings INI file: value containing semicolon

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

I'm trying to read and edit a Desktop Entry `.desktop` file using Qt QSettings. The problem is that these files contain keys with multiple values separated by semicolon `;`. I tried reading these as QStringList but no luck. I only get the first value. For example:

```
Keywords=disc;cdrom;dvd;burn;audio;video;
Categories=GTK;GNOME;AudioVideo;Audio;Video;DiscBurning;
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;application/x-cdrdao-toc;application/x-cue;application/x-toc;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-mp3-playlist;audio/x-mpegurl;application/x-brasero;x-content/audio-cdda;x-content/video-dvd;x-content/video-vcd;x-content/video-svcd;x-content/image-picturecd;
```

Getting the values with:

```
settings.value("Desktop Entry/MimeType").toStringList();
settings.value("Desktop Entry/MimeType").toString();
```

returns only the first value (in my example: `disc`, `GTK` or `application/x-cd-image`).

**How to I return the full value from those keys? And how do I write it back using `QSettings`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** (first attempt was completely useless)

**Variant 1**

```
QMap<QString, QString> settings;
QFile inFile("<input filename.ini>");
if(inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
  QTextStream in(&inFile);
  while (!in.atEnd())
  {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    QStringList linelist = line.split("=");
    settings[linelist[0]] = linelist[1];
  }
}
```

**Variant 2**

use `QSettings::registerFormat()`.

This is probably the only "clean" way to do it with `QSettings`. The advantage is that you can register it with the .desktop extension. You'll have to write a pair of `ReadFunc()` and `WriteFunc()` functions.

Comment: I was also thinking to something similar to what you proposed in Variant 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do it. `QSettings` has certain interpretation of .ini file [format](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#Format-enum), which is very close to Windows interpretation, and is not meant for generic parsing. Semicolon starts a [comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Comments), and apparently `QSettings` allows comment after value until end of line, and AFAIK there's no way around it.

You need to find a different library to handle .desktop files, or implement one yourself.

Comment: I guessed so :( But I believed semicolon means comment only at the beginning of the line... Anyway, I'll write my own `.desktop` file parser.

Comment: @Cornelius Wikipedia page (added link) mentions that there are variations about comments. But if you want to make sure there's no way around it with QSettings, there's always the source code...